text-transparent utility class not applying in TailwindCSS
I am trying to apply a gradient to some text with this guide. Everything is working up until trying to make the text transparent to allow the gradient to come through. This is what I end up with:

The edges of the text show the gradient, but the actual text is still black. Here are the style classes being applied:
<body class="w-screen h-screen bg-bg font-poppins">                            
  <main class="w-full h-full">                                                 
    <div class="sticky top-0 left-0 w-full bg-bg">                                   
      <h1 class="text-transparent bg-gradient-to-r from-blue via-cyan to-purple inline-block text-4xl p-4 bg-clip-text">Lorem Ipsum</h1>                     
      <hr />                                                                       
    </div>                                                             
  </main>                                                                      
</body>


I tried text-transparent, text-opacity-0, and text-slate-400/0- none of them worked. Am I applying this utility class incorrectly? I am rendering the page with Laravel and Blade templates, and I am building the css assets between changes.

Forgot to add, the blue/cyan/purple colors are custom colors defined in taiwlind.config.js and work correctly in other areas.

Have you used your browser devtools to see exactly what CSS is being produced? And a runnable snippet would help us help you.

Could you supply you Tailwind configuration please?

Enable bg-clip-text in Tailwind CSS: You might need to explicitly enable utilities in your tailwind.config.js file. Here's how you can check if backgroundClip is enabled:


// tailwind.config.js
module.exports = {
  // ...
  theme: {
    extend: {
      backgroundClip: ['text']
    }
  }
}



The text-transparent class is being applied correctly and not overwritten by another rule. It should work as it effectively sets color: transparent;.
The CSS property background-clip: text is somewhat notorious for compatibility issues, especially with certain versions of browsers.


.gradient-text {
    background: linear-gradient(to right, blue, cyan, purple);
    -webkit-background-clip: text;
    background-clip: text;
    color: transparent;
  }
<body class="w-screen h-screen bg-bg font-poppins">
  <main class="w-full h-full">
    <div class="sticky top-0 left-0 w-full bg-bg">
      <h1 class="gradient-text inline-block text-4xl p-4">Lorem Ipsum</h1>
      <hr />
    </div>
  </main>
</body>



Clear Cache
